# Joining two database tables with django

Tags: python, database, django

I am doing several measurements of voltage, resistance, frequency, etc. of a device.
I want to have a table for each measurement as well as a main table with the serial number of the device and boolean values if it has passed the tests.

I planned to have the structure similar to this:

```
create table volt(serial char(20),v1 float(10),v2 float(10)....)
create table resistance(serial char(20),r1 float(10),r2 float(10)....)
create table device(serial char(20),freq boolean(),tx boolean....)
```

I admit to not having a lot of experience with django and I have no idea how to create a model like this. I tried making seperate classes and using foreignKey, but for that I'd have to create the resistance and volt measurements first.

It is possible to store the measurement values as comma seperated strings as well, but I'd rather have it in a proper database.

Any hints?

Comment: Try the tutorial, it will get you started on the basics of model creation.  If you have specific problems once you've created your initial models bring them here.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Voltage`, `Resistance`, etc. models should have a `ForeignKey` to the `Device` model.

Comment: Say if I had 1500 columns in a database, could I turn that into a list in the model?